# How to create .msi setup package for Visual Studio 2008 Add-in?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, installation, add-in

I've created an Add-In for Visual Studio 2008. The only thing remaining is to create a setup package so that others can install and use my Add-In.

How can I do this in Visual Studio?

I tried creating a simple setup package, inserting files into the Add-Ins folder in the user's Documents folder, and it all worked as expected, except that the Add-In didn't show up in their Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found a guide to creating an MSI setup package for Visual Studio Add-Ins. It's located here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/AddinCustomAction.aspx